# Running setState prop function hang Maximum call stack

Tags: reactjs

On my template js I have the following

```
 updateBarTitle(title){
    this.setState({barTItle:title});
 }
 render() {
 const childrenWithProps  = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
             var childProps = {
                updateBarTitle: this.updateBarTitle.bind(this)
            };
            var childWithProps = React.cloneElement(child, childProps);
            return childWithProps;
        }, this);
```

And on the child I have.

```
 componentDidUpdate(){
    this.props.updateBarTitle('Users');
 }
```

When testing out the app and once state changes my browser freezes for a long time then returns a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` Need some advice on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating an infinite loop with the child `componentDidUpdate(`) method. It calls `updateBarTitle()`, which calls `setState()`, which re-renders, which calls `updateBarTitle()` again...and so on.

If you want that logic in the componentDidUpdate() method where you have it, you need to add some condition so that it will only call once.

You could pass the current state of barTitle to the child as a prop and then do something like:

```
if(this.props.barTitle !== 'Users') {
  this.props.updateBarTitle('Users');
}
```

To stop that loop from happening for example.

**EDIT:** To give a clearer example here is a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONeagq) of this to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for why this was happening, I changed `componentDidUpdate()` to `componentDidMount` and everything seems to be working. However I'm worried I'm doing an unforeseen error.

Comment: Well `componentDidMount()` won't keep firing in the same way `componentDidUpdate()` will, but it is still generally discouraged for the same reason. You should add a stop condition to the updates or re-structure your logic if you can.

Comment: Could you recommend me on my approach, the purpose of `ComponentDidMount` is to update the layout component with a new value on loading of the component. I might be trying `componentWillMount`, however this might be discouraged too as you stated.

Comment: Understood now, Thanks for the help!